# adding a prefix before the number to the list of remarkboxes for the tocbasic package

Tags: tocbasic

I have the following question: does anyone know how to add a prefix to the list of remarkboxes created with the `tocbasic` package? There is a "name" option in the `\DeclareNewTOC` command. It displays a short prefix before the number in the body of the report for each occurrence of `\begin{remarkbox} caption[...]... \end{remarkbox}`. I would like this prefix to also appear in the list at the end of the work before each item number.
What I mean is a command that works similarly to those below when modifying the list of drawings:

```
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{Fig.}
\addtolength\cftfignumwidth{15 pt}
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{.}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Regards
Piotr

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Rather than just providing code snippets, please provide a short, compileable example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: See, e.g., `entrynumberformat` in table 15.1 of the user manual. See also the documentation on how to use these features with with `\DeclareNewTOC` in section 15.6.

Comment: If you are using a KOMA-Script class, option `listof=entryprefix` could also be interesting. See the manual for more information.